# MomentJs Get Years - Not Difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the years included within the given date range.

Such that a user and input Dec. 1st 2015 - July. 1st 2016. I can get 2015 but I need to include 2016 as well.

Currently I am doing the difference between the two dates as years:

```
   var tmpStart = moment($scope.dates1.startDate);
    var tmpEnd = moment($scope.dates1.endDate);
    var years = tmpEnd.diff(tmpStart, 'year');
    for (var i = 0; i < years+1; i++) {
        var tmpD = moment($scope.dates1.startDate);
        tmpD.add(i, 'years');
        sc.dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(tmpD.format('YYYY')).withTitle('Total ' + tmpD.format('YYYY')));
    }
```

What is the best way to do this? I am sure I can just parse the year as int and compare to see how many years there are but I feel like that cannot be the proper way.

Comment: you don't need moment inside there. just get the start/end years, then loop betweeen them.: `s = 2014; e = 2016; for(y = s, y<=e, y++) { ...}` and get 2014/2015/2016 - it's not like there's ever (again) going to be a "leap year" where entire years gets skipped

Comment: So basically just parse the years out as int and compare

Comment: pretty much. you're not doing anything but generating year values anyways, so there's no point in banging around in moment for it. just treat the years at integers. now, if you DID have to deal with partial years, or funky increments ("+3 months 2 days") or whatever, then stick with moment. but this is a case where simpler is definitely better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $scope.startDate = '01/01/2014';
    $scope.endDate = moment(d).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var tmpEndYear = moment(d).format("YYYY");
    var tmpStart = moment("20140101", "YYYYMMDD");
    sc.dtColumns = [DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('ProductNumber').withTitle('Item')];
    var tmpEnd = moment(d);
    $scope.dates1.startDate = moment("20140101", "YYYYMMDD");
    $scope.dates1.endDate = tmpEnd;
    for (var i = 2014; i <= tmpEndYear; i++) {
        sc.dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(i).withTitle('Total ' + i));
    }
    while (tmpEnd > tmpStart) {
        sc.months.push(tmpStart.format('MM-YYYY'));
        tmpStart.add(1, 'month');
    }
```

Did eventually parse the int out and use it from there.